# Retrofit2 error java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit2

I called **PATCH** web service  using Retrofit2 but **onResponse** is not called and the **onFailure** is called **Despite of** the operation of the service is succeeded on the server side **perfectly**

And whenever,I tried to use fiddler to check the service its working , i found the problem is that serializing the coming response of the service and when using fiddler i found that no content of the JSON response so the Retrofit service assumed that its failed because there is no content and it cannot serialize the EMPTY content 
and give me this error

```
java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1
```

**Fiddler raw Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.4
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2016 09:55:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Status: 200 OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

**Fiddler Json Response is empty**

**webservice in java**

```
Call<Object> call = TimeCapp.services.accept_invited_alerts(HomeActivity.api_token, alert_id);

call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse (Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response)
    {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            String x = response.body();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure (Call<Object>call, Throwable t)
    {
        String x = t.getMessage();//java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1
    }
}
```

I tried to replace **object** with String,JsonObject,emptyCalssBody .... but its failed

**the interface of the webservice**

```
@PATCH("alerts/{alert_id}/accept")
Call<Object> accept_invited_alerts(@Header("X-Api-Token") String  
api_token, @Path("alert_id") int alert_id);
```

Comment: just return void instead, if the body is empty

Comment: i replaced the object type with Void type in java code and not changed in webservice return ,thanks for your hint so you can post the answer to accept and mark it :) @Bhargav

Answer (score 131, accepted):

just return void instead, if the body is empty

```
@PATCH("alerts/{alert_id}/accept") Call<Void> accept_invited_alerts(@Header("X-Api-Token") String api_token, @Path("alert_id") int alert_id);
```

for retrofit with Rx java you can use something like this

```
@PATCH("alerts/{alert_id}/accept") Observable<Response<Void>> accept_invited_alerts(@Header("X-Api-Token") String api_token, @Path("alert_id") int alert_id);
```

EDIT: For kotlin

```kotlin
@PATCH("alerts/{alert_id}/accept")
fun accept_invited_alerts(@Header("X-Api-Token")  api_token: String, @Path("alert_id") alert_id: Int): Call<Unit>
```

and

```kotlin
@PATCH("alerts/{alert_id}/accept")
fun accept_invited_alerts(@Header("X-Api-Token") api_token: String, @Path("alert_id") alert_id: Int): Observable<Response<Unit>>
```

Answer (score 28):

You can create **NullOnEmptyConverterFactory.class** :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Converter;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;


public class NullOnEmptyConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        final Converter<ResponseBody, ?> delegate = retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(this, type, annotations);
        return new Converter<ResponseBody, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object convert(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {
                if (body.contentLength() == 0) return null;
                return delegate.convert(body);               
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and add to code create. For ex:

```
 UploadImageNghiemThuApi uploadService = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Config.URL+"/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            // -----add here-------
            .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
            //---------------------
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(UploadImageNghiemThuApi.class);
```

I hope it can help your problem.
Thanks!

EDIT !!!

For a kotlin usecase you can check this

```
class NullOnEmptyConverterFactory : Converter.Factory() {
override fun responseBodyConverter(
    type: Type,
    annotations: Array<Annotation>,
    retrofit: Retrofit
): Converter<ResponseBody, *> {
    val delegate: Converter<ResponseBody, *> =
        retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter<Any>(this, type, annotations)
    return Converter { body -> if (body.contentLength() == 0L) null else delegate.convert(body) }
}
```

}

Comment: This did the job for me as I still want to read a potential error response body, but in success case there's no content, just a 200, cheers

Comment: This is the real way how it should be handled. Kudos to the author! :)

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. In case anyone's looking for the kotlin equivalent https://gist.github.com/rajivrnair/ddaef641d85b1dc402c72ac7e1cac0b6

Comment: Will it help for end of stream error by any chance?

Answer (score 6):

Thank you very much.

Api

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/rebu/insertusuario.php")
Call<Void> insertLogin(
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("senha") String senha,
        @Field("codCondutor") Long codCondutor
);
```

Class:

```
Call call = service.insertLogin(login.getEmail(), login.getSenha(), login.getCodCondutor());
```

Answer (score 0):

For me in laravel I was not sending any response after function completed just adding the following lines on server side helped.  This can be adapted to the language you are using.  **Just send some response from server side.**

```
use Response;

return Response::json(array(
            'result' => 'success',

        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue in my Spring Boot service.
The issue was with the **Content-Length** header value. Anything more than the specified no of bytes was causing the problem.

After removing the header, the issue got resolved.

You can either remove the header or try having a significant large value.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this kind of(Retrofit2 error java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1) exception which is an empty body exception. Yo need to pass the void.

```
  private void callCheck(){

    Api api = service.getTestClient().create(Api.class);

    Call<Void> call = api.SendRequest(Constant.client_id,Constant.client_secret,Constant.apiUserName);;

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, retrofit2.Response<Void> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
               //Perform according to it...
               // Here I am getting the response from the header...
            } else {
            // Is to handle the error body if an user provided the wrong values in the header...
                try {
           //these are for the error body
                    JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                    Log.d("ErrorBody:", jsonObject.toString());


                   JSONObject responseObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("fault");
                    String fault = responseObj.getString("faultstring");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Fault: " + fault);

                    JSONObject responseObjDetail = responseObj.getJSONObject("detail");
                    String detail = responseObjDetail.getString("errorcode");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Detail: " + detail);
                }catch (JSONException | IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen in Kotlin if you're trying to use the Retrofit Result class such as in `Single<Result<Void>>` but instead of using the retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.Result class your code may be incorrectly using the kotlin.Result class.

If this is the problem, add the import line `import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.Result` so that your code will use the right class for Result.