# cannot get a value inside php file

Tags: php, backend

PHP file created with a verification function pass a value from Android to php file but I get an error message in the Android file and do not know the cause of the problem , try to find out the problem and modify what is necessary

```
// Error message: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

// php file :


<?php
// include Marei DB Class 

if(isset($_GET['value'])) {

    $test = $_GET['value'];
    //$obj
} else {
    $test = '';

}

?>
```

Comment: This error is not coming from this code. You are missing many details of the code. What is inside the DB.php? How did you end up with a java error? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Even if you remove : include 'DB.php'; Keep the same problem

Comment: Then as i said the error in not coming from this code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744795/retrofit2-error-java-io-eofexception-end-of-input-at-line-1-column-1